# What is "popular discipline"?

Tags: meaning

I was translate a page on Wikipedia, but i couldn't understand the meaning of "popular discipline".

> During World War II, the Air Ministry had forecast that Britain would suffer night air bombing attacks causing large numbers of civilian casualties and mass destruction. It was widely agreed that navigation and targeting would be more difficult if man-made lights on the ground could be extinguished. As early as July 1939, Public Information Leaflet No 2 (part of the Air Raid Precautions (A.R.P.) training literature) warned of the need for **popular discipline** to ensure that the blackout regulations were fully enforced during the blackout periods.
> (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackout_(wartime)#World_War_II)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*popular*, deriving from Latin *populus* (the people), is not always to do with being *liked* by many. It has a more general meaning that is relevant here.

*popular* = "involving or relating to ordinary people or to all the people who live in a country or area"

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/popular)

"*popular discipline*" therefore referred to the disciplined (organised and orderly) behaviour of the general population at that time.

Comment: Needed nowadays, though apparently not so popular among some social groups.

Comment: Agreed, despite it being a matter of opinion. Or do I mean “its being a matter of opinion”?